# Windows 10 System.Exception: Install failed. Please contact your software vendor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I'd like to create 2 apps from the same project(VS solution), both of them has the same functional with small differences. So I just made 2 copies of my solution and I changed solution name, namespace and asigned app to different Microsoft Store app. When I try to instal secnod app on phone I get:

```
2>caught exception: System.Exception: Install failed. Please contact your software vendor. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)
2>   at Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperationWithProgress`2.GetResults()
2>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImmersiveProjectServices.PlatformShim.AppxCancelableDeployOp.Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImmersiveProjectServices.PlatformShim.IAppxCancelableDeployOp.Execute()
2>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImmersiveProjectServices.Shared.AppxLayoutManager.RunDeployOpWithCancel(IAppxCancelableDeployOp deployOp, CancelManager cancel)
2>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImmersiveProjectServices.Shared.AppxLayoutManager.RegisterPackage(String location, DeployPackageName deployPackageName, CancelManager cancel)
2>   at ImmersiveDeploy.Program.ExecuteTask(String[] args, Int32 argument, XDocument immersiveDeployResults, ImmersiveDeployTask task, DeployPackageName deployPackageName)
2>   at ImmersiveDeploy.Program.Main(String[] args), 
2>
2>*** End of logging from deployment agent ***
2>Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Install failed. Please contact your software vendor. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF9)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Projects build report:
  Status    | Project [Config|platform]
 -----------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Succeeded | BackgroundTaskRawNotification\BackgroundTaskRawNotification.csproj [Debug|x86]
  Succeeded | MySolution\MyApp.csproj [Debug|x86]
  Failed    | MySolution\MyApp.csproj [Debug|x86]
```

As is mentioned in other questions, if I uninstall one of them, the second is installing but I'd like to made some changes to install both of them. Have to mention that on PC I can install both apps from Visual Studio with no errors.

I am using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Visual Studio Version 14.0.24720.00 Update1
- Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0

Any advices are appreciated.

P.s. In android we have gradle flavors that helps us to build different apps from the same Android Studio project, maybe there is something similar in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of reserving multiple names for an App is that the name has meaning for different languages. E.g. an English speaking person would understand "My Great App" and a German speaking e.g. "Meine tolle App". When you assign multiple names to the same App which is identified by it's ID you do not have two Apps but just one with multiple names. That is why you're getting the error.

You could try to change these IDs manually but the easiest, fastest and safest way would be to just let Visual Studio do the work by creating a new project and copy/paste/include your files.

Anyway if your intention is to create a "Free" and a "Pro" version you should consider doing it the recommended way and use in App purchases or create a trial version.

Comment: thx for your explanation, could you provide some relative info/docs about manually ID changing?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any docs on this. And you are probably better off creating a new project/solution for the second app and move files there. This would take less than an hour. Fiddling around with package id an so on can easily take a day I would guess. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/view-app-identity-details, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211441, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211473

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.appxmanifest` file, in the `Package` tab change the `Package Name` value. Notice how changing this will also change the `Package Family Name` as well.

Lastly, change the `Display Name` from the Application tab so you can differentiate the apps when ruuning.